# iOS Safari sticky element jumps when address bar shrinks

Tags: html, css, ios, mobile-safari

I want an element to be centered horizontally and vertically. The element should also be sticky on scroll.

For this I use `{ position: sticky; top: 50%; }`

The problem is, on safari the element jumps a bit down after the address bar is shrinked.

What I want is that the element does not jump and it should stay the position of vertical before the address bar is shrinked. How can I achieve that behaviour?

Use this site on a iOS device with a bottom address bar https://daffodil-foremost-piper.glitch.me/

Answer (score 0):

{ position: sticky; top: **50vh**; }

Top 50% is the visible Area of the screen minus the addressbar (when visible).
Top 50vh is the visible Area without regarding the addressbar

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).